# How to create a special for TYPO3 template without fileadmin and user_upload folder

Tags: typo3, typo3-extensions

We to create a  TYPO3  extension for the Templates, TypoScript, CSS, jQuery and all user uploads file.
The hosting company has a special setup for TYPO3 without fileadmin and user_upload folder. Additional they use Composer for extensions.
Can anyone let me know how to create a special setup for TYPO3 without fileadmin and user_upload folder?
Thanks in advance.
Regards
Sharmistha

Answer (score 1):

My recommondation: take a look at the [sitepackage builder](https://sitepackagebuilder.com/).

This create an extension for your template. It also create an composer file. No need to use this directly, but it should explain a lot of things.

Answer (score 0):

You could remove the default file storage (which is `fileadmin/`) if you have not/ will not allow any files for editors.
Or you have another/changed file storage (pointing to another folder), where editors store(?) and find their assets.

Comment: Thanks so much. Shall try it out.